# Replace String usage with CharSequences?

Tags: java, java-7

I want to replace `String` with `CharSequence`, in some utilities. Check this signature:

```
public String[] foo(String... input)
```

What would be the proper way to replace this? Maybe

```
public <T extends CharSequence> T[] foo(CharSequence... input)
```

?

Comment: Every string is a charsequence so why bother?

Comment: @pvg: but not every CharSequence is a String. This would allow use of CharBuffer, StringBuffers or StringBuilders if need be. Although I am not sure why he would need this flexibility.

Comment: Why not just `public String[] foo(CharSequence... input)`?

Comment: It really depends on what foo is actually supposed to do, on whether or not it's appropriate to change the return type and what it should be changed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence charSeq = "Some String";
String string = charSeq.toString();
```

Or what do you want to do?

Comment: Not this. I want to replace the usage of String with the CharSequence. Not to convert between.